# Edit multiples lines of same column in Vim using a single command?

Tags: vim, command, edit, multiple-columns, lines

Is there any way to edit (add/remove characters) multiples lines of same column in Vim using a single command?

For example,

```
Sky can be white
Sky can be black
Sky can be red
Sky can be purple
Sky can be green
Sky can be yellow
Sky can be blue
```

If we wants to add the string "not" in the 8th column of all lines from 2 to 6, using a single command, like below, how we can do it without using Visual Block (Ctrl-v)?

```
Sky can be white
Sky cannot be black
Sky cannot be red
Sky cannot be purple
Sky cannot be green
Sky cannot be yellow
Sky can be blue
```

Comment: What's so bad about blockwise visual mode?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions come to mind:

```
:2,6norm eeanot<CR>
```

We use `:norm[al]` to execute the normal mode command `eeanot` on lines 2 to 6.

```
:2,6s/can/&not<CR>
```

We run a classic substitution on lines 2 to 6. In the replacement part, `&` represents the matched text so we don't have to repeat `can` before `not`.